# Install mysql2 package manually - error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an instance of Sequelize in my app. When I use docker-compose to build and run the application it asks me to manually download mysql2 and even though I've tried to download it using --save and --g it wont work. Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'root', {
   host: database,
   port: 3307,
   dialect: 'mysql'
 });
```

Using the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6

  web:

    build: .
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    environment:
     - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/test
    links:
     - mongo
    depends_on:
     - mongo
    volumes:
     - .:/starter
     - /starter/node_modules

  database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "ticketgo"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    volumes:
     - "./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    ports:
     - "3307:3307"

  adminer:
    image: "adminer"
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
     - "database"
```

I get this error:

```
 Error: Please install mysql2 package manually
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem i installed mysql package

npm install -g mysql2

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this issue, I solved mine by `npm intall -g mysql2`. It happens if you install sequelize-cli globally, it might be bugged.